# Prove that function is *not* injective $g : \mathbb{Z} \to \mu_{102}$

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I have this math problem, that I can't seem to figure out.

> Let $\zeta = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{102}}.$  Define $g : \mathbb{Z} \to
>  \mu_{102}$ with the formula $g(n)= \zeta^{3n}$ for $ n \in
>  \mathbb{Z}$.  Show that $g$ is not injective.

I know that to prove that it is injective I do $g(c_1) = g(c_2)$ for $c_1, c_2\in \mathbb{Z}$.

So I get $\zeta^{3c_1} = \zeta^{3c_2}$. How do I prove that this is false? Thanks.

Comment: Injective: $g(c_1)=g(c_2)\Rightarrow c_1=c_2$. Noninjective: there exist $c_1,c_2$ with $c_1\neq c_2$ and $g(c_1)=g(c_2)$.

Comment: You haven't told us what $\mu_{102}$ means. Is that group of roots of $z^{102}=1$ in $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I believe so... This was all I was given.

Comment: Note, since $\mu_{102}$ is finite, then it cannot be injective, since $\mathbb Z$ is infinite. A real question would be, is the induced map $\mathbb Z/102\mathbb Z\to \mu_{102}$ injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g(34)=\zeta^{3(34)}=e^{2\pi i}=e^{4\pi i}=g(68)$